# DPDK sample app ipsec-secgw failing with virtio NIC

Tags: dpdk, ipsec

I tried running the DPDK ipsec-secgw sample app with the following versions

- DPDK version dpdk-stable-19.11.5
- OS CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
- Kernel 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64

NIC type and driver

- 0000:00:04.0 'Virtio network device 1000' drv=igb_uio unused=virtio_pci,uio_pci_generic

Command and cmd line args used to run the app

```
./build/ipsec-secgw -l 6 -w 00:04.0 -w 00:05.0 --vdev "crypto_null" --log-level 8 \
--socket-mem 1024 -- -p 0xf -P -u 0x2 \
--config="(0,0,6),(1,0,6)" -f /root/config_file
```

Output:

```
EAL: Detected 8 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:04.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 1af4:1000 net_virtio
EAL: PCI device 0000:00:05.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 1af4:1000 net_virtio
CRYPTODEV: Creating cryptodev crypto_null

CRYPTODEV: Initialisation parameters - name: crypto_null,socket id: 0, max queue pairs: 8
Promiscuous mode selected
librte_ipsec usage: disabled
replay window size: 0
ESN: disabled
SA flags: 0
Frag TTL: 10000000000 ns
Allocated mbuf pool on socket 0
CRYPTODEV: elt_size 64 is expanded to 176

Allocated session pool on socket 0
Allocated session priv pool on socket 0
Configuring device port 0:
Address: 52:54:00:A5:82:2D
Creating queues: nb_rx_queue=1 nb_tx_queue=1...
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: Error: port 0 required RX offloads: 0xe, avaialbe RX offloads: 0xa1d
```

Config file contents:

```
#SP IPv4 rules
sp ipv4 out esp protect 1005 pri 1 dst 192.168.105.0/24 sport 0:65535 dport 0:65535

#SA rules
sa out 1005 aead_algo aes-128-gcm aead_key 2b:7e:15:16:28:ae:d2:a6:ab:f7:15:88:09:cf:4f:3d:de:ad:be:ef \
mode ipv4-tunnel src 172.16.1.5 dst 172.16.2.5 \
port_id 1 \
type inline-crypto-offload \

sa in 5 aead_algo aes-128-gcm aead_key 2b:7e:15:16:28:ae:d2:a6:ab:f7:15:88:09:cf:4f:3d:de:ad:be:ef \
mode ipv4-tunnel src 172.16.1.5 dst 172.16.2.5 \
port_id 1 \
type inline-crypto-offload \

#Routing rules
rt ipv4 dst 172.16.2.5/32 port 1
rt ipv4 dst 192.168.105.10/32 port 0
```

It says that certain offload capabilities are missing.

I got the config file details and command line arguments from a DPDK test plan for Niantic NICs. Is the app only supposed to work with Niantic PFs/VFs. Is there anyway to get it to work with virtio paravirtualized NICs?

Instructions link followed:
[Instructions](https://doc.dpdk.org/dts/test_plans/inline_ipsec_test_plan.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPDK example `ipsec-gw` make use of RX offload `.offloads = DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_CHECKSUM`. For DPDK 19.11.5 LTS following are the list of devices which supports the same

```
axgbe       
dpaa2       
e1000       
enic        
hinic       
ixgbe       
mlx4        
mlx5        
mvneta      
mvpp2       
netvsc      
octeontx    
octeontx2   
sfc         
tap         
thunderx    
thunderx    
vmxnet3
```

DPDK RX Checksum offload is defined as `#define DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_CHECKSUM (DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_IPV4_CKSUM | DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_UDP_CKSUM | DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_TCP_CKSUM)`. Based on the error log `Cause: Error: port 0 required RX offloads: 0xe, available RX offloads: 0xa1d`, looks like `DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_IPV4_CKSUM` is not present in the PMD.

For the question *ipsec-gw only works for Niantic NIC* assumption **is not incorrect**. Becuase IPSEC-GW application can run any NIC which has RX offload checksum available. List is shared above.

For the question *Is there any way to get it to work with virtio para-virtualized NICs?* one can **always disable the RX_CHECKSUM and do the checksum of IPv4 in software**.  But you will need to edit the application and use [rte_ip_cksum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755041/dpdk-hw-offloaded-calculation-of-udp-checksum-not-working/62777421#62777421).

Comment: Thanks! Looks like virtio is not on the list.
So in the structure static struct rte_eth_conf port_conf
setting `.offloads = DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_CHECKSUM` to `.offloads = 0` should do the trick for now.
And perhaps use `rte_` library functions in `lib/librte_net/rte_ip.h` for calculating checksums in software.
I will make an attempt and let you know how that goes.

Comment: It looks like you have understood the problem with the explanation.  Kindly accept and upvte